# Recursive function (help me understand it by pen and paper)

Tags: c++, recursion

First of all I have to say that I can use recursive functions on easy examples like Fibonacci, but I can't understand how to dry run (solve with pen and paper) this recursion :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b)
{
    if(a>b)return a;
    return b;
}

int f(int a, int b)
{
    if(a==0)return b;
    return max( f(a-1,2*b), f(a-1,2*b+1) );
}

int main()
{ 
    cout<<f(8,0);
}
```

How do I do this with pen and paper, with say, `a = 5` and `b = 6`?

Comment: what do you mean without compiler?

Comment: You need to ask a question. What are you trying to solve? Why is it not working? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @yngum; I think he means "dry run".

Comment: @Pyrce; He asked a question to explain the above recursion.

Comment: Q: What is the question?  Where exactly are you having a problem?  Q: What do you mean "without a compiler"?  Are you planning on hand-editing binary machine code into an .exe file?  Finally: recursion will terminate if a >= 0.  What happens if "a" is negative?

Comment: @haccks No he said "I can't understand how solve this". Is there some change he needs to make? Is this code complete? There's no question.

Comment: without compiler means i have to solve that given code with pencil and paper . The question is how to find the output if i do cout<<f(8,0); ?

Comment: I think what the question is is pretty clear: using English language to help him/her follow the execution flow/predict the result without running the code. Instead of that, let me assure you that I, too, find that pretty hard. Other than writing down interim results with pen and pen paper (which is pretty much like following a debugger and so like running the program) I would have a hard time doing this. This is not a "natural" recursion, and only natural ones can be intuited easily by the human brain.

Comment: @gnometorule Yep thats very though for an assignment (the pretty senseless max call suggests that it is a assignment)

Comment: max function works like this: if a>b then return a, otherwise return b

Comment: @user3191545 We know what a max does, the question has already been answered. The point is just that max just complicates the function (and reduces performances too btw) without doing anything meanigful as `2b + 1` is always greater than `2b`

Comment: @Paranaix - what happens if its run with negative numbers?

Comment: @noloader if `b < 0` `2b + 1 > 2b` still applies. But your right that `int a` is potential unsafe and should be `unsigned int a` (in `f`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We have always a depth of `a` (8)
2. Each invocations calls itself 2 times, once `2b` and once `2b+1` is passed
3. The greater result of both calls is returned
4. As `2b + 1 > 2b` only the right site of the max call is meaningful (`2b + 1`)

Now lets do the first iterations mathematically:

```
2 * b + 1                           = 2^1 * b + 2^0
2 * (2^1 * b + 2^0) + 1             = 2^2 * b + 2^1 + 2^0
2 * (2^2 * b + 2^1 + 2^0) + 1       = 2^3 * b + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0
2 * (2^3 * b + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0) + 1 = 2^4 * b + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0
```

As you can see there is a system behind it. Because `b = 0` for the first iteration, we can ignore the left side. The final value is thus:

```
2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7
=
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128
= 
255
```

If we run the programm we get the exact same value

Answer (score 1):

Just to give some information there are algorithms that use a little more complex parameters, one basic example would be mergesort [image]

Merging is simple:

- Take two elements one from each array A and B.
- Compare them and place smaller of two (say from A) in sorted list.
- Take next element from A and compare with element in hand (from B).
- Repeat until one of the array is exhausted.
- Now place all remaining elements of non-empty array one by one.

[image]

[Maybe you can find this doc useful](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~bylander/cs2233/recursionhandout.pdf)

[Or maybe this one](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/algo08-tutorials/tutorial2b.pdf)

Comment: Or this one: [Solving Recurrences](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/99-recurrences.pdf), by Jeff Erickson.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to analyzse the funciton on paper, I'll paste the result for f(1, 2)

```
f(2, 1) =
  max( f(1, 2), f(1, 3) ) =
    max (  max(f(0, 4), f(0, 5) , max(f(0, 6), f(0, 7) ) =
      max ( max(4, 5) , max(6, 7) ) =
        max (5, 7) =
          7
```

Is up to you to follow the computations

Note: I'm also assuming you didn't miss a parenthesis here: `2*b+1`